# How to allow Contributor users to manage the permision for the document library's files and folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, item-level-permissions

I have the following requirements:-

1. we need to have around 10 users who can contribute to a document library, mainly add,edit,delete files and folders.
2. but only 2 contributor users out of the 10 users should be able to specify unique permission for the files and folders.

So now if i check the following checkbox, then all the 10 contributor users will have the ability to specify unique permission for the files and folders, so this will not work for us.
[image]

one approach i found is that i can create a copy of the built-in Contribute permission level, i name it "*Contribute with manage permissions*", and check these 2 additional permission levels:-
[image]

then inside the document library I grant the 2 users this new permission level "*Contribute with manage permissions*".. so now the 10 users can upload files and folders and only the 2 users can define unique perms ion for the folders through the new permission level.

**so i have the following 2 questions:-**

1. is my above approach -of granting some contributor users that ability to define unique permission on the files and folders- considered valid?
2. i am not sure why the above approach will allow the 2 contributor users to define unique permissions for the folders only,, but not for the files?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can define a custom role, assign that role the required permissions, and then grant the Contributors you want that role.

Answer (score 2):

1.Per my test, when you create a new permission level - contribute permission with manage permissions, then grant a user with custom permission for a library, the user can specify unique permission for the files and folders.

2.When you grant a user with custom permission for a library, the user can specify unique permission for the files and folders.